# Auth options in NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I'm following a tutorial on authentication (https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-authentication-in-nuxt-js) but whenever I'm implementing auth in nuxt.config.js it throws this error in my browser

TypeError
defuWEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3 is not a function

any idea what this is about? the website works if I comment out my auth configuration but I can't log in

I saw the documentation of auth but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Hi, without more code it's quite difficult to say here.

Comment: @kissu it's the same code on the website

Comment: Which part exactly is not working here?

Comment: @kissu it's step 4: setting up local scheme, whenever I add 

auth: {
        // Options 

it throws an error